# Interact with batch file while inactive

Tags: batch-file, cmd, keyboard, key, keypress

How can you interact with a batch file while you are in another window. EX: I have a batch file that saves the time to a text file "log.txt" Everytime you press the "Q" key. How can I make it so that say, I'm on Firefox, I can still press "Q" and it saves it to a log EVEN THOUGH I'm in active window Firefox.

Comment: You could try using AutoHotKey although it is an external application... I don't think there is a way to do this from the command line.